# git clone not downloading any files

Tags: git

I use git clone with ssh and I have set up the public key in both github and bitbucket. When I clone a repository from either one it accepts my credentials and downloads some files, but it just downloads all the files as part of my ".git" folder (which is 37 megabytes, just like the repository online, which has all the files with their contents in their correct locations). The files do not display in their normal locations on my computer when I clone it, however, and they are just stored as part of the .git folder itself. How do I get the files and folders to actually display?

Comment: What's the exact command you are running?

Answer (score 2):

That's what a git repo *is* — some stuff in a repository (as you say, the *.git* folder). If you want to *see* any of those files, you need to *check out a commit*. That causes the files that comprise that commit to be copied into the *working area* where you can actually (get this) work with them. Typically the way you will specify the commit is by saying the name of a branch; for example, you might say `git checkout master`, depending on the name of the primary branch.

I'm a little surprised that you're facing this issue, though, because when you say `git clone...`, Git usually does a `git checkout` of the primary branch for you. It may be that you asked for a bare clone or mirror clone or something which suppresses that behavior.